# Simple image upload with php not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to upload an image to the folder `/images` and keep its name

This is what i got:

html

```
<form action="script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="mynewimage"> 
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php

```
if (!empty($_FILES['mynewimage']['name'])) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mynewimage']['tmp_name'], "images/" . $_FILES["mynewimage"]["name"]);
}
```

/images folder is 777

error says:  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE

```
Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for uploading errors:

```
if (isset($_FILES['mynewimage']) && $_FILES['mynewimage']['error']==0) {
    ....
}else{
    die('Error uploading, code '.$_FILES['mynewimage']['error']);
}
```

Check error codes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: it says:  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE Value: 4; No file was uploaded.. what does no file mean?

Comment: That means the file hasn't arrived. Maybe the file is too big, php usually have a default 2MB limit. Try adding ths at the beginning of your PHP script: `ini_set('upload_max_filesize','32M');`

Comment: hm still the same.. the image isn't bigger than 700kb anyway

Comment: found the mistake.. i had more than one "mynewimage" inputs in my html

Answer (score 1):

Found it. There were more than one `<input type="file" name="mynewimage">` in my html